# NullReferenceException when retrieving values from LINQ to DataTable

Tags: linq, vb.net-2010, nullreferenceexception

I have an application that is loading data into a database in a background task. The values are retrieved from a datatable using LINQ, manipulated and stored in a new datatable. I'm getting a NullReferenceException error and I can't figure out why. I'm checking to see if the value coming from the LINQ query is null, and if it is, the variable is assigned properly. If, however, the LINQ query contains a value, I get a NullReferenceException "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error which really makes no sense to me. What am I doing wrong?

```vb
Dim pin = (From u In partdata.AsEnumerable() _
                Where u.Field(Of String)("PART_GRP") = sPartType And
                u.Field(Of String)("INVT_TYPE").Contains("A")
                Select oid = u.Field(Of String)("ID"), Position = u.Field(Of Integer?))


Dim pout = (From u In partdata.AsEnumerable() _
                Where u.Field(Of String)("PART_GRP") = sPartType And
                u.Field(Of String)("INVT_TYPE").Contains("B") Or u.Field(Of String)("INVT_TYPE").Contains("C")
                Select oid = u.Field(Of String)("ID"), Position = u.Field(Of Integer?))

If pin.Count > 0 And pout.Count > 0 Then

    For i = 0 To pout.Count - 1
        ioidID = pout(i).oid

        ' Parts In
        If pin(i).Position Is Nothing Then ' When "Position" is Null, it works and "" is assigned. When "position" is not null, I get a NullReferenceException error on this line.
            spinPosition = ""
        Else
            spinPosition = pin(i).Position
        End If
        ...
```

Comment: Which line throws the exception?  Which object is `null` (or `Nothing`) when this happens?

Comment: @David, the line that the debugger stops on is 'If pin(i).Position Is Nothing Then'. But it happens when this field has a value, when the field is actually null, it assigns "" as it should.

Comment: You're checking if `pin(i).Position` is `Nothing`, but you're not checking `pin(i)` itself.  If *that* is `Nothing` then you'd get that exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments to the question, it appears that `pin(i)` is `Nothing`.  This would cause the exception when you try to dereference it here:

```
pin(i).Position
```

Note that you define `pin` and `pout` as two separate collections, unrelated to one another.  You check that they both contain at least one value:

```
If pin.Count > 0 And pout.Count > 0 Then
```

But you never check that they contain the *same* number of values.  You assume this here:

```
For i = 0 To pout.Count - 1
```

If `pout` ever contains more values than `pin`, your code will fail.

Comment: Ahh okay, I see your point. Let me do some investigating along the lines of one set being larger than the other.